# Xpath Multiple Predicates

Tags: xpath

I am trying to quickly find a specific node using XPath but it seems my multiple predicates are not working. The div I need has a specific class, but there are 3 others that have it. I want to select the fourth one so I did the following:

```
//div[@class='myCLass' and 4]
```

However the "4" is being ignored. Any help? I am new to XPath.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a xpath query returns a node set you can always use the `[OFFSET]` operator to access a certain element of it.

Use the following query to access the fourth element that matches the `@class='myClass'` predicate:

```
//div[@class='myCLass'][4]
```

@WilliamNarmontas answer might be an alternative to the syntax showed above.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

```
//div[@class='myCLass' and position()=4]
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works correctly only if all of the div elements have the same parent. Otherwise use:

```
(//div[@class='myCLass'])[4]
```

Comment: Hi @TheGateKeeper, I'd like to second the above answer and give it an alternative shape, a bit longer but IMHO more readable: `/descendant::div[@class eq 'myClass'][4]`.